# How do I make status extend?

Tags: wxpython

I have a frame with a text editor and a status bar that shows the line and column the cursor is in. How do I make it so that when the status bar extends, the status bar's column showing the width does too?

Code:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import os

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)

        self.control.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.LineColumn)

        self.Status_Bar()

    def Status_Bar(self):
        #Status Bar
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.SetStatusWidths([-140, 60, 140])
        self.LineColumn(self)

    def LineColumn(self, e):
        line = self.control.GetCurrentLine() + 1
        col = self.control.GetColumn(self.control.GetCurrentPos())
        stat = "Ln: %s, Col: %s" % (line, col)
        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(stat, 1)

    def RandomText(self, e):
        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText("Random Text", 3)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a variable width field for the middle item that displays the line and column numbers.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.StatusBar.html#wx.StatusBar.SetStatusWidths),

> There are two types of fields: fixed widths and variable width fields.
>   For the fixed width fields you should specify their (constant) width
>   in pixels. For the variable width fields, specify a negative number
>   which indicates how the field should expand: the space left for all
>   variable width fields is divided between them according to the
>   absolute value of this number. A variable width field with width of -2
>   gets twice as much of it as a field with width -1 and so on.
>
> For example, to create one fixed width field of width 100 in the right
>   part of the status bar and two more fields which get 66% and 33% of
>   the remaining space correspondingly, you should use an array
>   containing -2, -1 and 100.

So if you change the line `self.SetStatusWidths([-140, 60, 140])` to `self.SetStatusWidths([-2, -1, 100])`, the middle portion of the status bar that's showing the numbers will expand as described in the quote above.

You can change the numbers used in `SetStatusWidths` to whatever you want.  `self.SetStatusWidths([-1, -1, -1])`  should make all the columns expand equally.  `self.SetStatusWidths([-1, -2, -1])` should make the middle column twice as wide as the others.  And so on.

I mostly use c++ and I'm not an expert with wxPython, so I may have the syntax slightly wrong, but that's the basic idea.  I hope that helps.